# Incorrect string value written to a cell using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a string variable price.

```
Dim price As String
```

`price` is storing a value 301.20.But when I am trying to write it to a cell using

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4).Cells(1,1) = price
```

It is writing 22.

**Note** : I debugged it and in this mode I found that it is writing correct value(301.20) to the cell.
But when I run it,it is printing the wrong value.

**EDIT** :

Take a look at the below code

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.Visible = False
ie.navigate "url1"
Set htmldoc = ie.document

ie.navigate "url2"
Set htmldoc1 = ie.document

Dim element As Object
Set element = htmldoc1.getElementById("lastPrice")

Dim price As String
price = element.innerText

ThisWorkbook.Sheets(4).Cells(1, 1) = price
```

**url1** has an element with id **lastPrice**.It is printing `innertext` of this element.

What actually it should do?
Search element with id **lastPrice** from **url2** and print its `innertext`

Magically in debug mode it is printing the appropriate value.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Something else is going on in your code, but we don't have enough info to debug your problem (only one line of code).  If price really has a value of 301.20 it's difficult to see how it would write "22" to A1.  Is it possible it's writing to a different sheet from the one you think it is ?

Comment: Like Tim said, it is hard to debug with just one line of code.  It could be that it is putting the value in a different location, or it could be the formatting of cell A1.  I didn't find any formatting that turned 301.20 into 22, but there are some formats that make certain numbers look different.  Try copying and pasting values in a different cell to double check.  Also, you might want to consider making price a number instead of a string.  I don't think that will solve your problem, but it could save you from having any issues elsewhere in your code depending on what you want to do.

Comment: I thought that formatting the cell as "dd" might make this happen but formatting 301.20 that way gives 27 (for 1900-10-27). I also tried switching to the 1904 date system but that gives 28 (for 1904-10-28)

Comment: I had cleared all the formatting.Also I tried copying to some other cell but got same result

Comment: Ok I have got the problem so I am editing the question.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this.

**Define enum**

```
Enum READYSTATE
READYSTATE_UNINITIALIZED = 0
READYSTATE_LOADING = 1
READYSTATE_LOADED = 2
READYSTATE_INTERACTIVE = 3
READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
End Enum
```

**Add below code**

```
ie.navigate url2

'Added this

Do While ie.READYSTATE <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.StatusBar = "Trying to go to url2 ..."
DoEvents
Loop

Set htmldoc1 = ie.document
```

Now because we have ordered to do events until READYSTATE_COMPLETE,it navigates to url2 and then takes the HTML document into htmldoc1.

Thanks